# Files are not obscured by the bind mount of docker

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker and I have been referring to the Docker documentation about storage:

> If you mount a **bind mount or non-empty volume** into a directory in the container in which some files or directories exist, these files or directories are obscured by the mount

I attempted to mount an **empty** data directory on the host system to a MySQL container using the following command:

```bash
docker run --name mysql -v /home/whc/data/docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test -d mysql:5.7
```

However, upon checking the directory on the host, I noticed that it was no longer empty and that the files had been copied from the container into the bind mount.

```bash
[whc@linux mysql]$ pwd
/home/whc/data/docker/mysql
[whc@linux mysql]$ ll
total 188476
-rw-r----- 1 polkitd input       56 Jan 27 22:10 auto.cnf
-rw------- 1 polkitd input     1676 Jan 27 22:10 ca-key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 polkitd input     1112 Jan 27 22:10 ca.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 polkitd input     1112 Jan 27 22:10 client-cert.pem
-rw------- 1 polkitd input     1676 Jan 27 22:10 client-key.pem
-rw-r----- 1 polkitd input     1352 Jan 27 22:10 ib_buffer_pool
-rw-r----- 1 polkitd input 79691776 Jan 27 22:10 ibdata1
-rw-r----- 1 polkitd input 50331648 Jan 27 22:10 ib_logfile0
-rw-r----- 1 polkitd input 50331648 Jan 27 22:10 ib_logfile1
-rw-r----- 1 polkitd input 12582912 Jan 27 22:10 ibtmp1
drwxr-x--- 2 polkitd input     4096 Jan 27 22:10 mysql
drwxr-x--- 2 polkitd input     4096 Jan 27 22:10 performance_schema
-rw------- 1 polkitd input     1680 Jan 27 22:10 private_key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 polkitd input      452 Jan 27 22:10 public_key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 polkitd input     1112 Jan 27 22:10 server-cert.pem
-rw------- 1 polkitd input     1676 Jan 27 22:10 server-key.pem
drwxr-x--- 2 polkitd input    12288 Jan 27 22:10 sys
```

This result confused me because I thought that the empty bind mount would obscure the directory in the container, and therefore remain empty.

Comment: I have [an explanation](/a/65955679) of this behavior in [Docker: Strange behaviour of bind mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65955098/docker-strange-behaviour-of-bind-mount); does that explanation help?

Comment: @DavidMaze That was a very clear answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how MySQL container works:

1. Starting startup script
2. Looking into `/var/lib/mysql`
3. If it's empty, it has to create needed files, because they are required to work
4. If files were already there just reuse them

In your case container got empty directory, so it has to recreate all the files, and you can see all of them have current time